# Php error on localhost. Error 403

Tags: php, xampp

I am currently getting an error with php using XAMPP. The error is:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
```

I have no changes made to the config of XAMPP and was unable to find away to fix this. I have read about the error and tried suggested fixs, none of which work for me or others that tried them.

A bit more info on this, it only happens after clicking a submit button ().

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be very much appricated

Comment: Which submit button are you clicking?

Comment: what is the URL you are trying to access ?

Comment: you probably didn't route to the right file and tried browsing to a folder. if you add empty index.html file in that folder, you'll see no error but not what you expecting.

Comment: describe the problem better because from this we can not do anything

Comment: The submit button been clicked is <input type="submit" value="Log in"> and the URL I am accessing is http://localhost/Loginform.inc.php , if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is probably not running. i once had this problem with apache2 php5 and apache-php5-mod(from my package repository) on linux.
I could only serve plain html(no php) files untill i fixed it.

Does a simple php_info() file work?
Is the page with the submit button a .php or a .html?

If the phpinfo file fails try making a simple php info and running it from the command line(without the apache server)
(to do this):
1. open windows explorer.
2. navigate to php.exe
3. in the address bar, enter "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" (a window should open.)
4. in the window type "php.exe PATH_TO_PHPINFO_FILE\FILENAME.php"
Please tell me what it outputs.